# How to show both colormaps in the legend in GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm trying to plot the percentage of missed votes by representatives in California but taking care to color according to political party. I am able to plot two colormaps using GeoPandas on the same plot, but I cannot get both colormaps to show on the legend.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

california = merged[merged['STATENAME'] == 'California']

rs = california[california['party'] == 'R']
ds = california[california['party'] == 'D']
# set the value column that will be visualised
variable = 'PCT'
# create map
rs.plot(column=variable, ax=ax, legend=False, cmap='Reds', scheme='quantiles', k=7)
ds.plot(column=variable, ax=ax, legend=True, cmap='Blues', scheme='quantiles', k=7)
```

The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Why have you legend=False on the rs plot?
Can you provide us with data?

Comment: Could you change legend=False into legend=True and rerun the script.

Comment: @squeezer44 

Setting both lines to Legend=True doesn't change anything. When I posted this I was playing around with using one or the other to see if it would work and I forgot to change it back.

Here's the sample data I used to generate the California plot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lp5CeMyC88cFBRRxfOmAevo6UHeDU0za/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make sure you have references to both legend objects:
in your example the first one you instantiated (and it's shown), the second one you don't (it's not shown).

In general that means:

```
# Add first legend: only labeled data is included
leg1 = ax.legend(loc='upper right')

# Add second legend
# leg1 will be removed from figure
leg2 = ax.legend(loc='lower left')

# Manually add the first legend back
ax.add_artist(leg1)
```

- Additional informations
  [Multiple legends on the same Axes](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes)
  [Multiple Legends on the Same Axes 2](https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/32429/multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes)

*ByTheWay: Your code example is incomplete: the imports and the conversion into a GeoDataFrame is missing.*