# Trying plot two geodataframes with two legends in the same plot in Geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science, geopandas

**I have gotten a trouble with multi layers in the same plot with geopandas**. I got plot both successfully separately, however to plot two legends (one to each) I could not. Below it is the code to read the datasets.

```
dfGeo = pd.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/dfGeo.csv', sep=',').dropna()
dfGeo.drop_duplicates(subset=['Link'], inplace=True)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfGeo, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(dfGeo.long, dfGeo.lat))
bairros = gpd.read_file('drive/MyDrive/bairros.geojson')
```

Below it is the code to plot the first map with legend to it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
bairros.plot(column='rpa', legend=True, categorical=True, ax=ax)
```

[image: first plot]

This is the first code to plot both layers without legend to each one

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
bins = mapc.Quantiles(gdf['Preco'], k=5).bins
ax.set_aspect('equal')
bairros.plot(ax=ax, color='gray', edgecolor='silver')
gdf.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', markersize=12, color='gold')
plt.show()
```

[image: second plot]

At end it is the code trying to plot both with legend to each one, but unsuccessfully the only one legend appeared from the second plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
bins = mapc.Quantiles(gdf['Preco'], k=5).bins
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# legend this doesn't appear
bairros.plot(column='rpa', legend=True, categorical=True, ax=ax)

# legend this appear    
gdf.plot(column='Preco', cmap='inferno', ax=ax, marker='o', markersize=12, legend=True, scheme="User_Defined", classification_kwds=dict(bins=bins))

plt.show()
```

[image: third plot]

I would like to plot and putting the legend of both in the same plot. How could I do it?
**Obs:** I tried a solution from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005381/how-to-show-both-colormaps-in-the-legend-in-geopandas), but the output changed without any legend.

[fourth plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI77C.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the [answer you linked to](/q/63005381/) seems to have the solution. Can you just show us your code trying to implement the solution and show us where you're stuck?

Comment: Well, I tried that answer however the legends comes out blank and two messages comes out in the output with the map ->

**No handles with labels found to put in legend**

Comment: got it - that's a pretty common matplotlib error I'm sure we could work through. can you ask about that error specifically and show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: Thanks you. The code that I used is above. I put all the codes from each Jupyter cell in this issue and the ask is to plot one map with two legends of each geodataframe 

Comment: I’m saying rather than posting code that does work but doesn’t do what you want, can you post your attempt to do what you want along with the error message, and we can help you debug it?